# How does matrix multiplication scale with optimized linalg libraries?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, hpc, intel-mkl

What is the scaling of matrix-matrix multiplications when using an optimized linear algebra library (let's consider MKL and OpenBLAS)? I did some googling and the Strassen algorithm came up, which is O(N^2.807) scaling, but I couldn't find a clear answer. Can anybody confirm this or is there a better algorithm that is used instead these days?

I'm asking because I'm seeing unexpected scaling in my code. The matrices are quite large and I wonder if it's really all the `pdgemm`s taking up the time, something that I usually don't have to worry about at all.

Comment: This is a very broad question indeed.  Practitioners are often more interested in how off-the-shelf code scales than the theoretical scaling of neat algorithms such as Strassen or Coopersmith-Winograd or what have you.  Not all of those neat algorithms look so appealing after they've been through the mill of modern CPU architectures with their multiple cache layers, vectorised f-p units, and uncle-tom-cobbly and all.  For anything like a good answer you'll have to post a much more pointed (i.e. to the point) question.

Comment: Thanks. Does it really depend that much on the specific case (whether there's cache reuse, vectorization, etc.)? My guess is that the things you mentioned influence the prefactor but the exponent is probably still around 2.8. But I'm not sure, that's why I asked.

Comment: I'm very sure all those BLAS-implementations do use the classic O(n^3) alg. [Read also this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23172/strassen-algorithm-vs-standard-multiplication-for-matrices).

Comment: You might think so, but in practice, as @sascha has pointed out, the most commonly encountered linear algebra libraries, the ones that work with the kinds of numbers that CPU hardware deals with (ie generally 32- and 64-bit f-p values) all (to my knowledge) use the naive matrix-matrix multiplication algorithm optimised six ways to last Sunday.  The more sophisticated algorithms with their `O(n^less-than-3)` are only encountered in systems targeting multiple-precision arithmetic and sometimes, even in those systems, only employed for numbers with humongous digit counts

Comment: Thanks everybody. These answers have been very informative.